# What decimal value does the 8-bit binary number 11011111 have if it is on a computer using signed-magnitude representation?

Tags: binary, signed, representation, magnitude

I am confused on how to present this in decimal value

Would it be just the negative value of 223 or would it be -125?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be just the negative value of 223 or would it be -125?

Neither. Signed magnitude representation reserves one bit to represent the sign, and the remaining bits make up the value.

In this case:

- bits 0-6 are 1011111, which is 95 in decimal
- bit 7 is 1, meaning the value is negative

So the result is -95.

As for your calculation of -125, it appears you got that backwards. 125 is 1111101 in binary. Definitely got your wires crossed there.